# Bad return type in lambda in case of Generics

Tags: java, generics, lambda, compiler-errors, java-8

Having this generics code

```
static final <T> List<Class<? extends T>> findSubClasses(Class<T> clz, String packageName){
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(clz));
    Set<BeanDefinition> beanDefinitions = provider.findCandidateComponents(packageName);
    List<Class<? extends T>> subClasses = beanDefinitions.stream().map(b->mapToClass(b, clz)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return subClasses;
}

private static final <T> Class<? extends T> mapToClass(BeanDefinition beanDefinition, Class<T> clz) {
   String className = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
   try {
       return (Class<? extends T>) Class.forName(className);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       log.error("Failed to load the scanned class {}", className, e);
   }
   return null;
}
```

I have this error message on the `b->mapToClass(b, clz)`

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: Class<capture of ? extends T> cannot be converted to Class<Object>
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case where <strike>the compiler</strike> IntelliJ does not properly infer the return type of the `map()` operation.

You can help it by simply providing the new stream item type: `Class<? extends T>` like this:

```
List<Class<? extends T>> subClasses = beanDefinitions.stream()
        .<Class<? extends T>>map(b-> mapToClass(b, clz))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that it only seems to be a bug in IntelliJ, as javac appears to happily compile it (as expected).

As a side node, you can avoid the unchecked cast in `mapToClass()` by writing it as follows:

```
return Class.forName(className).asSubclass(clz);
```

Comment: Still the case with IntelliJ 2022.2.4 _and also_ javac 17.0.5, but this workaround works to shut both up.

Answer (score 0):

the generic information that you provide to those methods is *un-related*, even if you give them the same name (`T`). If you want to make them somehow related, you need to declare them at the class level instead.

But in such a case it would not work because your methods are `static`; as such this would work for example:

```
 public class YourClass<T> {

    final List<Class<? extends T>> findSubClasses(Class<T> clz, String packageName) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(clz));
        Set<BeanDefinition> beanDefinitions = provider.findCandidateComponents(packageName);
        List<Class<? extends T>> subClasses = beanDefinitions.stream().map(b -> mapToClass(b, clz))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return subClasses;
    }

    private final Class<? extends T> mapToClass(BeanDefinition beanDefinition, Class<T> clz) {
        String className = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
        try {
            return (Class<? extends T>) Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Indeed as [Didier's points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473608/1059372) this works just fine with `javac-8` and `javac-9` and thus no need to do any refactoring at all...